# Numpy: improve fancy indexing on arrays

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, slice

Looking for faster fancy indexing for numpy, the code I am running slows down, at `np.take()`. I tried `order=F/C` with `np.reshape()`, no improvement. Python `operator` works well without the double `transpose`, but with them is equal to `np.take().`

```
p    = np.random.randn(3500, 51)
rows = np.asarray(range(p.shape[0]))
cols = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30,40,50])

%timeit p[rows][:, cols]
%timeit p.take(cols, axis = 1 )
%timeit np.asarray(operator.itemgetter(*cols)(p.T)).T

1000 loops, best of 3: 301 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
```

Comment: How about `p[:,cols]` as it seems you are just slicing columns? Don't think there's anything better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test of several options:

```
In [3]: p[rows][:,cols].shape
Out[3]: (3500, 16)
In [4]: p[rows[:,None],cols].shape
Out[4]: (3500, 16)
In [5]: p[:,cols].shape
Out[5]: (3500, 16)
In [6]: p.take(cols,axis=1).shape
Out[6]: (3500, 16)
```

time tests - plain `p[:,cols]` is fastest.  Use a slice where possible.

```
In [7]: timeit p[rows][:,cols].shape
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
In [8]: timeit p.take(cols,axis=1).shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 739 µs per loop
In [9]: timeit p[rows[:,None],cols].shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
In [10]: timeit p[:,cols].shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop
```

I've seen `itemgetter` used for lists, but not arrays.  It's a class that iterates of a set of indexes.  These 2 lines are doing the same thing:

```
In [23]: timeit np.asarray(operator.itemgetter(*cols)(p.T)).T.shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 738 µs per loop
In [24]: timeit np.array([p.T[c] for c in cols]).T.shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 748 µs per loop
```

Notice that `p.T[c]` is `p.T[c,:]` or `p[:,c].T`.  With relatively few `cols`, and by ignoring advanced indexing with `rows`, it times close to `p[:,cols]`.